# How to convert NSDate to NSString?

Tags: iphone

I want to convert NSDate to NSString?
How's that possible?

I tried this, but it didn't work (it is generating Exception) :

```
   NSString *dateToString=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:(NSString *)dateObj];
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can achieve this with the `NSDateFormatter`.

Example:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

NSString *string = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
[dateFormatter release];
```

For more ways of controlling the format of the string, see the reference documentation for [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).