# NSDate get year/month/day

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdatecomponents, nscalendar

How can I get the year/month/day of a `NSDate` object, given no other information? I realize that I could probably do this with something similar to this:

```
NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] init];
NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:0 fromDate:date];
int year = [components year];
int month = [components month];
int day = [components day];
```

But that seems to be a whole lot of hassle for something as simple as getting a `NSDate`'s year/month/day. Is there any other solution?

Comment: I had a bit of trouble using this code until I changed the first line to "NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];" There must have been a change to the API since this question was asked.

Comment: @futureelite7 rolled back to revision 1. The code there is for historical purposes, and was a simple explanation of what my initial idea was.

Comment: The code no longer works. Can you make a note to the correct code?

Comment: @futureelite7 no. That code was a showing of my first attempt, it was never intended to work. If you feel that that is ambiguous, feel free to edit the context surrounding that code block, but don't edit the code itself. If you feel extremely strongly about editing the code itself, then please take this coversation to meta and we'll see what other mods have to say.

Comment: Agreed.. this code doesn't work.  It just sets year, month and day to 0.

Comment: @mike thats why you read the answers, not the question.

Answer (score 623, accepted):

Because this is apparently my most popular answer, I'll try to edit it to contain a little bit more information.

Despite its name, `NSDate` in and of itself simply marks a point in machine time, not a date. There's no correlation between the point in time specified by an `NSDate` and a year, month, or day. For that, you have to refer to a calendar. Any given point in time will return different date information based on what calendar you're looking at (dates are not the same in both the Gregorian and Jewish calendars, for instance), and while the Gregorian calendar is the most widely used calendar in the world - I'm assuming - we're a little biased that `NSDate` should always use it. `NSDate`, luckily, is far more bipartisan.

---

Getting date and time is going to have to pass through `NSCalendar`, as you mentioned, but there's a simpler way to do it:

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

That generates an `NSDateComponents` object containing the day, month, and year from the current system calendar for the current day. (**Note:** this isn't necessarily the current *user-specified* calendar, just the default system one.)

Of course, if you're using a different calendar or date, you can easily change that. A list of  available calendars and calendar units can be found in the [`NSCalendar` Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSCalendarUnit). More information about `NSDateComponents` can be found in the [`NSDateComponents` Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

---

For reference, accessing individual components from the `NSDateComponents` is rather easy:

```
NSInteger day = [components day];
NSInteger month = [components month];
NSInteger year = [components year];
```

You just have to be mindful: `NSDateComponents` won't contain valid information for any fields you ask for unless you generated them with that valid information (i.e. request `NSCalendar` to provide that information with `NSCalendarUnit`s). `NSDateComponents` contain no reference information in and of themselves - they're just simple structures that hold numbers for you to access. If you want to also get an era, for instance, out of `NSDateComponents`, you'll have to feed the generator method from `NSCalendar` with the `NSCalendarUnitEra` flag.

Comment: A correction to this, the first line should have NSDayCalendarUnit instead of NSWeekCalendarUnit.

Comment: @Erik Which calendar are you using? Code?

Comment: I removed my comment because it was ignorant.  ;)  It was showing the 29th becuase 2012-04-30 GMT is five hours earlier here in Texas...  Sorry, your code is fine.

Comment: @Erik No worries — I had a feeling something like that was the case. :)

Comment: Be careful [NSCalendar currentCalendar] is a very expensive method each time executed

Comment: @Pascalius Asking just out of curiosity: expensive compared to what? And what makes it especially expensive?

Comment: @ItaiFerber [NSCalendar currentCalendar] seems to be a global object but in fact a complete roundtrip is made to create a new calender instance. Many calls and your perfomance will be wasted. Instead you should cache the object.

Comment: @Pascalius Oh, of course. I thought you meant it shouldn't be used in favor of a different method.

Comment: Try setting your iDevice to japanese or thai time mode and you'll get a different year number for the same point in time. 2013 is year 25 in the Japanese calendar.

Comment: @Jonny The results you get depend on the calendar you're using. `NSCalendar`'s `+currentCalendar` method will return the system calendar, and so if the user's phone is set to the Japanese or Thai time mode, you'll get a different year. If you want to force a specific calendar system, create a calendar and initialize it with the proper locale. For instance, to force a Gregorian calendar, you'll want to use the following: `[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar]`

Comment: Uh yeah that's what I said

Comment: @Jonny Sorry; it wasn't clear to me what you'd meant — I thought you were asking a question. My mistake.

Comment: enums NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit are DEPRECATED use NSCalendarUnitDay instead.

Comment: @KunalBalani Thanks for that — the online documentation hasn't been updated yet for `NSCalendar`, but I'll make note of that in my answer.

Comment: [NSCalendar currentCalendar] is much much faster in iOS 7 if and only if you don't call setter methods on it (i.e. the expense moves to the first setter method call, instead of the currentCalendar call).

Comment: Warning: Don't use [NSCalendar currentCalendar] unless you're trying to show a value to the user. Consider that users might follow a Buddhist calendar (the year now is 2558 or something), or any other number of odd calendars. You don't want your app to break in these cases. Use the gregorian calendar unless you have a very specific reason not to. This bug is hard to catch because you and your testers might all use gregorian as default.

Comment: how can I get the day of the year e.g 10 April is the current day is the 99th day of the current year??

Comment: @iOSDeveloper There is no date component which represents "day of the year". Instead, you can use [`-[NSCalendar ordinalityOfUnit:inUnit:forDate:]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscalendar/1408595-ordinalityofunit?language=objc) (passing in `NSCalendarUnitDay` and `NSCalendarUnitYear`, along with the date of your choosing) to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 50):

You can get separate component of a NSDate using NSDateFormatter:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[df setDateFormat:@"dd"];
myDayString = [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

[df setDateFormat:@"MMM"];
myMonthString = [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

[df setDateFormat:@"yy"];
myYearString = [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

If you wish to get month's number instead of abbreviation, use "MM". If you wish to get integers, use `[myDayString intValue];`

Comment: Expanded upon his with [this gist](https://gist.github.com/2033820). Have fun--- you can drop this into your code.

Comment: Solved my problem for using dates to lookup in a dictionary :) Thanks!

Comment: This actually doesn’t work 100% as expected all the time. For example, if the NSDate is 2013-12-31 00:00:00 +0000 then the formatted date will return 2014 for year, even if the actual number in the date is 2013.

Comment: how can I get the day of the year e.g 10 April is the current day is the 99th day of the current year?? –

Answer (score 18):

Just to reword Itai's excellent (and working!) code, here's what a sample helper class would look like, to return the *year* value of a given NSDate variable.

As you can see, it's easy enough to modify this code to get the month or day.

```
+(int)getYear:(NSDate*)date
{
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:date];

    int year = [components year];
    int month = [components month];
    int day = [components day];

    return year;
}
```

(I can't believe we're having to write our own basic iOS date functions like this, in 2013...)

One other thing:  don't ever use < and > to compare two NSDate values.

XCode will happily accept such code (without any errors or warnings), but its results are a lottery.  You *must* use the "compare" function to compare NSDates:

```
if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedDescending) {
    // date1 is greater than date2        
}
```

Comment: The results of pointer comparison are far from a lottery - they have very well defined results, so long as you use them for what they are intended for - comparing pointers, not objects.

Comment: It might not be a lottery, but C#'s DateTime is far more intuitive.  In iOS, the less-than operator really should compare two NSDates... would anyone really want to compare the pointers of two NSDate variables ?  At the very least, XCode show show a Warning to ask if this is really what the user really means.

Comment: That's just a sign of a lazy coder who doesn't understand the fundamentals of the language he's writing in. And, there have been situations for me where pointer comparisons are necessary for ObjC objects - especially if you're making a custom container (though things get weirder with ARC).

Comment: I must be a lazy coder who doesn't understand the fundamentals, but that's a great tip Mike!

Comment: Pointer comparisons may be necessary but they are the far less common use case when comparing two dates.  99.99% of the time any programmer would be more interested in comparing the dates rather than the pointers.  Fundamentally C# and the .NET framework were designed to make the most common scenarios easier, thus making programmers more productive, and in many cases objective-c feels like it makes things intentionally more arduous.  If you have time to read an 800 page book on the fundamentals of every language, cheers, but the rest of us have apps to deliver on time and on budget.

Comment: how can I get the day of the year e.g 10 April is the current day is the 99th day of the current year?? –

Answer (score 16):

In Swift 2.0:

```
    let date = NSDate()
    let calendar = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
    let components = calendar.components([.Month, .Day], fromDate: date)

    let (month, day) = (components.month, components.day)
```

Answer (score 11):

I'm writing this answer because it's the only approach that doesn't give you optionals back from `NSDateComponent` variables and/or force unwrapping those variables (also for Swift 3).

Swift 3

```
let date = Date()
let cal = Calendar.current
let year = cal.component(.year, from: date)
let month = cal.component(.month, from: date)
let day = cal.component(.day, from: date)
```

Swift 2

```
let date = NSDate()
let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let year = cal.component(.Year, fromDate: date)
let month = cal.component(.Month, fromDate: date)
let day = cal.component(.Day, fromDate: date)
```

Bonus Swift 3 fun version

```
let date = Date()
let component = { (unit) in return Calendar.current().component(unit, from: date) }
let year = component(.year)
let month = component(.month)
let day = component(.day)
```

Comment: how can I get the day of the year e.g 10 April is the current day is the 99th day of the current year?? –

Comment: And make sure you use Gregorian calendar, e.g. year component for Japanese calendar returns 1 digit..

Answer (score 9):

#### New In iOS 8

**ObjC**

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSInteger era, year, month, day;
[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] getEra:&era year:&year month:&month day:&day fromDate:date];
```

**Swift**

```
let date = NSDate.init()
var era = 0, year = 0, month = 0, day = 0
NSCalendar.currentCalendar().getEra(&era, year:&year, month:&month, day:&day, fromDate: date)
```

Comment: Amazing! @Yuchen Zhong

Comment: Brilliant ! Way better syntax !

Answer (score 6):

As of iOS 8.0 (and OS X 10) you can use the **component** method to simplify getting a single date component like so:

```
int year = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] component:NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Should make things simpler and hopefully this is implemented efficiently.

Answer (score 5):

If you are targeting iOS 8+ you can use the new `NSCalendar` convenience methods to achieve this in a more terse format.

First create an `NSCalendar` and use whatever `NSDate` is required.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
```

You could extract components individually via `component:fromDate:`

```
NSInteger year = [calendar component:NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:date];
NSInteger month = [calendar component:NSCalendarUnitMonth fromDate:date];
NSInteger day = [calendar component:NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:date];
```

Or, even more succinctly, use `NSInteger` pointers via `getEra:year:month:day:fromDate:`

```
NSInteger year, month, day;
[calendar getEra:nil year:&year month:&month day:&day fromDate:date];
```

For more information and examples check out [NSDate Manipulation Made Easy in iOS 8](http://pivotallabs.com/?p=32104). Disclaimer, I wrote the post.

Comment: how can I get the day of the year e.g 10 April is the current day is the 99th day of the current year?? –

Answer (score 3):

```
    NSDate *currDate = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar*       calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents* components = [calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:currDate];
    NSInteger         day = [components day];
    NSInteger         month = [components month];
    NSInteger         year = [components year];
    NSLog(@"%d/%d/%d", day, month, year);
```

Comment: That quite clearly doesn't give me the year, month or day as an integer, which is what I requested in the OP. -1.

Comment: Richard J. Ross III: I have just fixed it, Im sorry because my answer was lost your question.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to get the individual NSDateComponents from NSDate, you would definitely need the solution suggested by Itai Ferber. But if you want [to go from NSDate directly to an NSString, you can use NSDateFormatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775401/how-to-convert-nsdate-to-nsstring).

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
    NSString *birthday = @"06/15/1977";
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:birthday];
    if(date!=nil) {
        NSInteger age = [date timeIntervalSinceNow]/31556926;
        NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:date];
        NSInteger day = [components day];
        NSInteger month = [components month];
        NSInteger year = [components year];

        NSLog(@"Day:%d Month:%d Year:%d Age:%d",day,month,year,age);
    }
    [formatter release];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this . . .

**Code snippet:**

```
 NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];
 int year = [components year];
 int month = [components month];
 int day = [components day];
```

It gives current year, month, date

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution in Swift:

```
let todayDate = NSDate()
let calendar = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!

// Use a mask to extract the required components. Extract only the required components, since it'll be expensive to compute all available values.
let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitYear | .CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitDay, fromDate: todayDate)

var (year, month, date) = (components.year, components.month, components.day)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift**

Easier way to get any elements of date as an optional String.

```
extension Date {

  // Year 
  var currentYear: String? {
    return getDateComponent(dateFormat: "yy")
    //return getDateComponent(dateFormat: "yyyy")
  }

  // Month 
  var currentMonth: String? {
    return getDateComponent(dateFormat: "M")
    //return getDateComponent(dateFormat: "MM")
    //return getDateComponent(dateFormat: "MMM")
    //return getDateComponent(dateFormat: "MMMM")
  }


  // Day
  var currentDay: String? {
    return getDateComponent(dateFormat: "dd")
    //return getDateComponent(dateFormat: "d")
  }


  func getDateComponent(dateFormat: String) -> String? {
    let format = DateFormatter()
    format.dateFormat = dateFormat
    return format.string(from: self)
  }


}

let today = Date()
print("Current Year - \(today.currentYear)")  // result Current Year - Optional("2017")
print("Current Month - \(today.currentMonth)")  // result Current Month - Optional("7")
print("Current Day - \(today.currentDay)")  // result Current Day - Optional("10")
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 2.x

```
extension NSDate {
    func currentDateInDayMonthYear() -> String {
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "d LLLL yyyy"
        return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(self)
    }
}
```

You can use it as

```
NSDate().currentDateInDayMonthYear()
```

Output

```
6 March 2016
```

Answer (score 0):

i do in this way ....

```
NSDate * mydate = [NSDate date];

NSCalendar * mycalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSCalendarUnit units = NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay;

NSDateComponents * myComponents  = [mycalendar components:units fromDate:mydate];

NSLog(@"%d-%d-%d",myComponents.day,myComponents.month,myComponents.year);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get human readable string (day, month, year), you may do:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
NSString *string = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateEndDate];
```