# How to find what day of the week for any given date using Cocoa?

Tags: iphone, nsdatecomponents

I know this is a repetitive query, but I am stuck up with this issue.
I need to know how can I get the day like Mon,Tues for a particular date eg: 18 July, 2010 etc.

appreciate your help!!

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694867/nsdate-get-year-month-day?

Comment: Are you trying to print out "Mon", if that is the case, you'll want to leverage the NSDateFormatter

Comment: @Greg: I just wrote in abbreviation but it should be Monday, Tuesday etc.

Comment: Right, I mean are you looking for the textual version rather than the numeric representation.  Check out the documentation for NSDateFormatter.  There are formatting strings that will give you pretty much any variation of what you are asking for.

Comment: @Greg: It should be in numeric representation. eg: Sunday = 0, Monday =1, etc.

Comment: In that case, this is a duplicate and the link @Mat posted should help you.

Comment: That's not going to help me. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *dateString = @"20 July, 2011"; // select this from your database

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM, yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
NSInteger weekday = [components weekday];
NSLog(@"%d", weekday);
```

Note that Sunday is 1.
2 would be Monday etc...

Edited my answer to show you an example of how to convert a string to an NSDate. ;)

Comment: pawan.mangal's solution would return the weekday as a string, probably even localized. However, if you'd want to store it in a database or something similar, an integer might be more useful.

Comment: You are checking every time the current date, lets say I select 11 December 2007 from my list, I wanted to what is the day number for that particular day. Hope I am clear to you.

Comment: Well, you'd have to convert that string (?) to an NSDate and use it instead of [NSDate date]; ;)

Comment: There are enough codes on SO to show you how to create a NSDate object for another date then the current one.

Comment: Added an example of how to get an NSDate from a string.

Comment: Thanks Jenox.That was really helpful,though it was dumb to ask converting string to NSDate.

Answer (score 1):

To print out the textual representation of a the day from and NSDate, try the following:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
[dateFormatter release];

NSDate *myDate = [NSDate date];

NSString *day = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate];
```

For more information on http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
NSDateFormatter* theDateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [theDateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
    [theDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
    NSString *weekDay =  [theDateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Comment: Please check my comments to Jenox's answer.