# How do I split the current time into 3 strings; hours, minutes, and seconds

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm making a clock app, and I want to display the current time, with the components (hours minutes, seconds) spaced out. I think that the only way to do that is to separate the time into three strings. How do I do that?

```
- (void)updateTime {

    [updateTimer invalidate];
    updateTimer = nil;

    currentTime = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [timeFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    lblTime.text = [timeFormatter stringFromDate:currentTime];

    updateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple things here:

1 )  if you want a constantly running timer, don't invalidate it each time "`updateTime`" is called (and only call `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:` once... instead of at the end of each time "`updateTime`" is called).

2 ) it looks like you have a single label for displaying your time.  You should make your `timeFormatter` an ivar (instance variable, so it's created and set only once) and then you can set the format via:

```
timeFormatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm:ss";
```

And you should be all set.

Your new `updateTime` method could look like this:

```
- (void)updateTime {    
    currentTime = [NSDate date];
    lblTime.text = [timeFormatter stringFromDate:currentTime];    
}
```

3 ) If you want three different labels, you need to declare IBOutlets for the three labels and have three different date formatters.  For example:

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController ()
{
    IBOutlet UILabel * hourLabel; // you need to connect these in your XIB/storyboard
    IBOutlet UILabel * minuteLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel * secondLabel;

    NSDateFormatter * hourFormatter;
    NSDateFormatter * minuteFormatter;
    NSDateFormatter * secondFormatter;
}
```

Then, in your "`viewDidLoad:`" method, set up your formatters:

```
hourFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init;
hourFormatter.dateFormatter = @"HH";
minuteFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init;
minuteFormatter.dateFormatter = @"mm";
secondFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init;
secondFormatter.dateFormatter = @"ss";
```

And finally, in your "`updateTime`" method:

```
- (void)updateTime {    
    currentTime = [NSDate date];
    if(hourFormatter)
    {
        if(hourLabel)
        {
            hourLabel.text = [hourFormatter stringFromDate: currentTime];
        } else {
            NSLog( @"you need to connect your hourLabel outlet in your storyboard or XIB" );
        }
    } else {
        NSLog( @"you need to allocate and init and set hourFormatter");
    }
    minuteLabel.text = [minuteFormatter stringFromDate: currentTime];
    secondLabel.text = [secondFormatter stringFromDate: currentTime];
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Objective-C, will this create three separate strings? I want to be able to have three labels for hours, minutes, seconds, so that I can place them in different locations on the view.

Comment: @user2397282 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694867/nsdate-get-year-month-day

Comment: Sorry again, but I've done exactly as you've said, but it just doesn't show up

Comment: With the 'updateTime' method, is that all the code I need; do I need to keep anything I started with?

Comment: In order for this timer to run, you need to "keep" the three formatters and the three label outlets and a timer.  What else do you mean by "need to keep anything I started with?".

Comment: Woops, I deleted the current time variable and that's why it wasn't working! Thank you ever so much, you've been fantastic help!

Comment: Using `NSDateComponents` would be a much better choice than creating three `NSDateFormatter` objects and formatting an `NSDate` three times.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a single string, you can change

```
[timeFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
```

to

```
[timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];
```

Comment: Can you split that string into "hh", ""mm", and "ss"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use to separate hh, mm, ss by using

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSInteger hour = [components hour];
NSInteger minutes = [components minute];
NSInteger seconds = [components second];
```