# Win32's GetLocalTime() on iOS

Tags: c++, ios, c, winapi

What is the iOS equivalent for these three Win32 functions? I'm finding a lot of answers on how to return the date & time as a string on iOS, but I just want the individual integers.
I want the LOCAL date/time, not UTC time. Found a few iOS examples on that, but they seem excessively and needlessly complicated. There's got to be an easier way.

```
int GetCurrentMonth(void)
{
    SYSTEMTIME date;
    GetLocalTime(&date);

    return date.wMonth;
}

int GetCurrentDay(void)
{
    SYSTEMTIME date;
    GetLocalTime(&date);

    return date.wDay;
}

int GetCurrentYear(void)
{
    SYSTEMTIME date;
    GetLocalTime(&date);

    return date.wYear;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694867/nsdate-get-year-month-day

Comment: yeah, you should mark this question for closing as a duplicate @Stavash