# Formatting a date for just the day number "dd"

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter, date-format

I would like to get the day number from a date. I have the following code which is producing undesirable output:

```
NSDateFormatter* numDay = [[MSDateFormatter alloc]init];
numDay.dateFormat = @"DD";
dateString = [numDay stringFromDate:the_dte];
DayNum.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", dateString];
```

For instance, if `the_dte` is `2014-01-07` I get a `dayNum` of `38`

I would like `dayNum` to hold 7 instead. I assume it has to do with my format. I just do not know a format to put it in to get what I want.

Comment: Refer to [the documentation](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns).  For day of month use "d" or "dd".  "DD" will get you day of year (though haven't a clue why it's 38 for the 7th).  And there is no formatter code to get day of week -- for that you'd need to use NSCalendarComponents.

Comment: Bookmark that site -- it will save you hours of flailing around.

Comment: And Hot Licks beats me once again.  Darn you!  (Well done.)

Answer (score 0):

In your example `the_dte` should be an NSDate.  If that is the case then I think you should read [this answer to get exactly what you are looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3695408/1671729).

Basically you can get the date components from an NSDate by

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:the_dte];
NSInteger day = [components day];
NSInteger month = [components month];
NSInteger year = [components year];
```

Then format those components into whatever strings you would like using NSString's `stringWithFormat:` and assign that to your label text