# Performing IBAction depending on the current time.

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

How can I perform two actions depending on the current time?

For example: Display labelA if current time is between 8am-2pm.
Display labelB if current time is between 2pm-6pm.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why an `IBAction`? Just do this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.labelA.text = @"It's between 8am and 2pm";
    self.labelB.text = @"It's between 2pm and 6pm";

    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *gregorianCal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *dateComps = [gregorianCal components: (NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit)
                                                  fromDate: date];
    if (dateComps.hour > 8 && dateComps.hour <= 14)
    {
        [self.view addSubview:self.labelA];
    }
    else if (dateComps.hour > 14 && dateComps.hour < 18)
    {
        [self.view addSubview:self.labelB];
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I want to get my text for the label from a text field?

Comment: @user3771552 Well, that's a separate question, and why would you want to make a label's text the text of a textfield? Why not just have a textfield? If you insist, it's as simple as `labelA.text = textField.text`

Comment: Also, you don't need both labelA & labelB. You can use one label object, then change it's text value depending on the time of day. Much simpler.

Comment: @JasonMcDermott indeed

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSDateComponents` to convert the current time (which you get from `[NSDate date]`) into components like hour, minute, etc. Then just check the hour component to see what range it's in and do the appropriate label action based on that.

See: [NSDate get year/month/day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694867/nsdate-get-year-month-day)