# How to put countDownDuration time from my picker into an integer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdatepicker

I found how I log the time picked:

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
        NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:[datePicker date]]);
}
```

What I want to accomplish is:

I have a model class which is a sub-class of NSManagedObject, this is a class I created from my .model entity.

whenever I click "save" method I want to give the model class the count down time, so each object of this class will have it's countdown time and I can fire it up for each object...

i'm a beginner so it will be helpful if you can give me some guidance in what type of object should I store the count down time selected, and this is why I though putting it inside an integer but from what I see it's not true.

Thanks

Comment: What number are you trying to get? The date can be stored in a model class directly as an NSDate or an NSTimeInterval since a reference date. Why are you trying to assign a date to an integer?

Comment: date and integer? what is the relation?

Comment: You said you want to put countDownDuration into an int, but then you show sampleCode where you access datePicker.date. Why don't you access datePicker.countDownDuration? That's a NSTimeInterval, you can quite easily cast it to NSInteger.

Comment: hi shim, i added to the question what I want to accomplish so you can give me better tips..thanks!! @shim

Comment: hi buddy, i added more info to the question to make it more clear..would love to get your help @MatthiasBauch

Comment: @nickshmick What's wrong with simply doing `NSInteger duration = datePicker.countDownDuration;`?

Comment: Totally unclear what countdown you're talking about.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to extract the components of your NSDate. There's a class that does this: `NSDateComponents`.

Check out this other S.O. question for some guidance:

[NSDate get year/month/day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694867/nsdate-get-year-month-day)