# Convert DateTime String 24 Hr format from SQL to 12 Hr with Am/PM

Tags: ios, sql, objective-c

I am trying to solve an issue for quite a long time.... i used almost all formats in objective C but not getting proper result.

I have below string coming from SQL server along with other data:

> Aug 31 2015  14:40:11

I want to convert it like below:

> 8/31/2015 2:40 PM

My questions are:

- Do i have to change the way DateTime field being send from sql ?
- How i can achieve in Objective C ?

Comment: show your already tried code

Comment: If the database is sending you a datetime object, treat it as such.  Don't treat it as a string.

Comment: @DanBracuk Yes, but sometimes the DB sends all values as string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-YYYY hh:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"Aug 31 2015 14:40:11"];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm a"];
NSLog(@"Your converted date - %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

Comment: i notice for above answer it shows null, if date is in AM then date show correct .... but for above it shows date as null...can u plz help me out in this

Comment: NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"Aug 31 2015 14:40:11"];

Comment: Here you have to pass your string in which you are getting the date, if you are getting the diffrent date format then you have to change @"dd-MMM-YYYY hh:mm:ss" to the format in which you are getting the date or else you will get nil.

Comment: [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-YYYY hh:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"Aug 31 2015 04:40:11"];   works fine. but  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-YYYY hh:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"Aug 31 2015 14:40:11"];  shows null only difference is time.....

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you get the date in the required format from SQL, since SQL server supports [several date formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to represent a date. On the other hand, if you want to manage in iOS, you have [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/) and [NSDateComponent](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/) classes.

Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694867/nsdate-get-year-month-day), see *loretoparisi's* solution.