# How to convert this Swift line into Objective-C syntax

Tags: objective-c, swift

Need to convert this to Objective-C syntax, can't seem to find a way to convert it.

```
   private class func components(fromDate fromDate: NSDate) -> NSDateComponents! {
        return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(NSDate.componentFlags(), fromDate: fromDate)
    }
```

Tried this:

```
- (NSDateComponents *) componentsFromDate: (NSDate *) fromDate {
    return [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] componentsFromDate: [NSDate componentFlags] : fromDate];
}
```

This was defined before:

```
- (NSCalendarUnit *) componentFlags {
    return NSCalendarUnitYear, NSCalendarUnitMonth, NSCalendarUnitDay, NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear, NSCalendarUnitHour, NSCalendarUnitMinute, NSCalendarUnitSecond, NSCalendarUnitWeekday, NSCalendarUnitWeekdayOrdinal, NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear;
}
```

All this in a category I created:

```
@implementation NSDate (AFDateHelperObjC)
@end
```

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694867/nsdate-get-year-month-day

Comment: Forgot a detail. Edited question.

Comment: What error are you getting in Objective C?

Comment: expression result unused for the componentFlags method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need:

```
- (NSDateComponents *) componentsFromDate: (NSDate *) fromDate {
    return [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:[NSDate componentFlags] fromDate:fromDate];
}
```

The name of the method in `NSCalendar` is `components:fromDate:`.

And your `componentsFlags` method that you added to `NSDate` as a category method needs to be a class method, not an instance method. In both the .h and .m of the category, change the `-` to `+`. And the return type needs to be `NSCalendarUnit`, not `NSCalendarUnit *`. And you need to use bitwise OR to join all of the flags together.

```
+ (NSCalendarUnit) componentFlags {
    return NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond | NSCalendarUnitWeekday | NSCalendarUnitWeekdayOrdinal | NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear;
}
```

Comment: Tells me : no known class method for selector: "componentFlags"

Comment: Oh yeah. That makes sense. Where did you define that `componentsFlags` method you added to your question? If it was added to `NSDate` as a category method, it should be a class method, not an instance method (change the `-` to a `+`).

Comment: 1 last minor remark from XCode: - expression result unused for the componentFlags method.

Comment: One more edit. There were lots of issues wit the `componentFlags` method that I overlooked initially.

Comment: Thx ! Answer confirmed !