# FSCalender selected date

Tags: ios

I am using FSCalender through cocoa pods. I simply want to get the selected date/month/year. I am only getting current date. I am getting details like this :-

```
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];  
    formatter.dateFormat = @"dd.MM.yyyy";  
    NSString *string = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]; 
    NSLog(@"CurrentDate=%@",string);
```

In string, I am getting output :- 
CurrentDate=08.02.2017

How to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can set current date to "[formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]" so you get current date

Comment: I am already getting current date. My question is how to get any selected date ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a delegate method in FSCalendar for this

```
// FSCalendarDelegate
- (void)calendar:(FSCalendar *)calendar didSelectDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    // Do something
    // get year , month and day of selected date.

NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:date];

NSInteger day = [components day];
NSInteger month = [components month];
NSInteger year = [components year];

}
```

Here you will get a object of **NSDate**, and then you can convert it into your desired format.

Please read the full documentation of this library [FSCalendar](https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar/blob/master/MOREUSAGE.md)

To get **day/Month/year** from **Date** you can refer following [Stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694867/nsdate-get-year-month-day) :

Comment: There is a issue how to get date, month, year separately in this delegate method ? An how to hide FSCalender view date selection.?

Comment: I have add code for get day/month and year..check that out

Comment: Through which we are getting date, month, year on current date basis, not selected date  basis.

Comment: In delegate you will get a **date** which is object of slected date. Use that instead of [NSDate date]